# Executing stored procedure in a loop until a condition is met using SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, stored-procedures, ssis

I have a customers table whose fields have to be updated with recent changes and also an additional column in the same table which specifies if that particular row has been updated or not, I have a procedure that does this for me

```
CustomerID  CustomerName Address Updated
   1           abc         xyz      Yes
   2           cdb         tyy       No
```

As you can see above , the second row hasn't been updated due to NO connection to the client server.Later when the connection to server is available, all I have to do is update the column value to blank and run the procedure again till the row is updated with any changes.

I have to flow this process  in a loop until all rows in the table are updated.
Could someone please help me out to do this in SSIS

Comment: Just add a Execute SQL Task on the top which updates all Updated = No to '' - And then you can run the flow over and over again.

Comment: Is there a possibility to implement an if condition or a loop to do that without any human intervention?

Comment: Why wouldn't you pull all of the records that are needed at once and not loop through this?

Answer (score 0):

The following will allow your stored procedure run until all the rows have been updated.  A couple important things to note, if it's possible that there will be one or more iterations where no rows in the table will have been updated, a condition, such as a T-SQL `IF` statement, will need to be added to the second Execute SQL Task to check for this and assign a value to the variable accordingly.  Also, the parameter syntax (using `?` for the parameter place holder) is for an OLE DB connection.

- Add a For Loop container, in the `EvalExpression` field, select an int variable and set the condition as the variable not equal to 0, i.e. `@[User::Count] != 0`
- Within the For Loop container, add an Execute SQL Task that executes the stored procedure
- Add another Execute SQL Task linked to the first one and still inside the For Loop, that has a query which returns the count of rows from the table without the updated value that will be mapped to the variable from the For Loop, such as

`select ? = count(*) from dbo.YourTable where Updated != 'Yes'`

- On the second Execute SQL Task, go to the Parameter Mapping pane, pick your variable in the Variable Name field, set the Direction to Output, Data Type to Long, and Parameter Name to 0.  The Parameter size can remain at the default of -1.